# Why is the lower bound for sorting strings Ω(d + nlogn)?

Tags: time-complexity, sorting, strings, lower-bounds

I'm taking an Advanced Algorithms course. I'm currently studying efficient algorithms for sorting strings. In this chapter, it is provided a lower bound for the time complexity of $\Omega(d + n\log{n})$, where d is the sum of the distinguishing prefixes of all the strings in our set S and n is the cardinality of the strings set S. The book says this is the minimum number of comparisons any algorithm must take, and I cannot figure out why. Can you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shall modify the question a bit and answer the following version, which I think is more correct:

> Prove that the lower bound of any *character-comparing* string sorting algorithm is $\Omega(d + n \log n)$, where $d$ is the sum of *the lengths* of the distinguishing prefixes of all the strings in our set $S$ and $n$ is the cardinality of the strings set $S$.

Term $d$ stems from the requirement of reading that many characters. If the first $k$ characters of two strings are the same, then one needs to check the $k+1$st character of those strings. Without reading the first $k$ of both, one cannot be ensured that the first $k$ characters are the same.

Note that, this explanation does not mention any requirement about repeated readings. This is a lower bound: It just mentions that the algorithm needs to access all of the characters of the distinguishing prefixes at least once.

$n$ is the number of elements in our set. To sort the strings, we need to compare and sort at least the distinguished characters of the set. So, sorting $n$ strings cannot be faster than sorting $n$ characters. In a character-comparing sorting algorithm, that cannot be done faster than $\Omega(n \log n)$.

Thus, the overall lower bound is $\Omega(d + n \log n)$.

Answer (score 2):

The time complexity you indicated is the *lower bound* of your specific problem. A lower bound is the worst-case running time of the *most optimized* *TM* that recognizes membership in the language.

Lover bound for sorting algorithms is $\Omega(n \log n)$ this means that it is not possible to do better than this and *all* the sorting cases (instances) may have a temporal complexity $t \geqslant\Omega(n \log n) $.

For a simple proof of the former lower bound you can take a look at [this](https://www.bowdoin.edu/~ltoma/teaching/cs231/fall07/Lectures/sortLB.pdf).

Comment: Ok, I have a clear understanding of what lower bounds are. I just don't understand why the lower bounds for sorting strings adds a d factor in the complexity.

Comment: That’s because comparing strings doesn’t happen by magic. If the first 20 characters of two strings are the same, that’s 40 characters you _must_ read or you can’t compare the strings.